# Why does Bootup.php run with PHP 5.4.16 from with Craft script but PHP 7.4.10 from the terminal command line?

Tags: php, install, installation, composer

This is a problem encountered apparently by a lot of users when installing from the Craft setup/install files from the Craft web site.

`PHP Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/craft/vendor/voku/portable-utf8/src/voku/helper/Bootup.php on li PHP Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /var/craft/vendor/voku/portablec/voku/helper/Bootup.php on line 27 Script @php craft setup/welcome handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 255`

The following scenario yields this error:

- A fresh install of craftcms
- installed with composer
- using these instructions: https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/install/files.html#what-s-composer
- On a bran new unused DigitalOcean Plesk/Centos7 machine
- with php aliased to the Plesk php 7.4 folder
- With CLI php -v verified as returning 7.4
- With all the required php extensions
- With the web server visited and phpver command verified as returning 7.4
- with composer updated

  `# composer depends danielstjules/stringy`

  `# voku/stringy 6.4.0 replaces danielstjules/stringy (~3.0)`

Diagnosing it, Right, putting `echo phpversion();` into Bootup.php and running from Bash returns 7.4.

But comment everything in Bootup.php out, put `echo phpversion();` into it and run craft, and when it calls Bootup.php, it returns 5.4.16.

Why is this?  Why does it run with a different php version when run from within the Craft script, and how is this fixed to run with 7.4?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you define your aliases? If you haven't already, you could start by adding directives for both php and composer in your `.bash_profile`.

The file should contain something like (alter paths as appropriate):

```
# Include the location of the PHP 7.4 binary in your path
export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin:$PATH
# Ensure that any calls to composer are run with the PHP 7.4 binary
alias composer='/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar'
```

Log out/in (or source .bash_profile) and run `php -v` to check it's picking up the correct binary, then have another go.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out the issue was due to a shebang in the Craft files, which ultimately led to `/usr/sbin/php`.  THe php *there* was php5.  I solved it by renaming php and adding a symbolic link `ln -s` from php to php7.4.  Does your solution solve this same problem?